# Physical interpretation of a stoichiometry matrix all zero entries

Tags: theoretical-biology

Consider the following set of biological reactions:

[image]

I've assumed that the state space of the system wrt to concentrations could be depicted by vector $s$ as below:

$\dot{s} = \begin{bmatrix}\dot{a}\\\dot{x}\\\dot{c}\\\dot{b}\end{bmatrix}$.

So the stoichiometry and reaction matrices could be acquired as the following:

$\dot{s} = \begin{bmatrix}\dot{a}\\\dot{x}\\\dot{c}\\\dot{b}\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}-1&1&0\\2&-2&-1\\0&0&1\\0&0&-1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}axk_{1}\\x^{2}k_{-1}\\bxk_{2}\end{bmatrix}$.

Now let's assume that *the concentrations of $A$ and $B$ (i.e. $a$ and $b$) are constant*, thereby $\dot{a} = \dot{b}=0$.

Therefore the stoichiometry matrix will be reduced to

$\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$.

It's a little bit weird and to me, it sounds like a system which has no evolving dynamics, as a totally static system of reactions, by which nothing is consumed or produced. Furthermore, the system always remains at $a=b=c=x=0$ as a global equilibrium point.

**Is it a valid conclusion?...**

In a general perspective, **what is the meaning zero-coefficients matrix in biology?**

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe I am missing something: you are talking about a system in which you have set all the concentrations to zero? I mean, sure, that's valid, but not particularly interesting - why do you care about such a system? I'm less familiar with the specific conventions you are using (linear algebra was a long time ago, and though I use applications of it all the time everything is numerical simulations rather than mathematical logic). And why do you think the meaning of a particular matrix would be different in biology vs. anywhere else?

Comment: I think [this question](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/24245/are-matrices-a-good-way-to-do-stoichiometry) from another SE site will help you understand a bit - maybe check in there and come back if you are still confused?

Comment: @BryanKrause: `Answer1`: I'm just setting two of the concentrations to zero, $a$ and $b$ not all of them! Furthermore. `Answer 2`: Because such zero matrix is not a dynamic representation in general theory of dynamic systems. Since I'm not a biologist, I'm just wondering whether there is something necessary to be considered in the scope of biology to interpret such situation.

Comment: Can you stick to a convention? Are we using A and B or a and b? or are you using them to represent something different? It seems to me that if B is zero, the second equation is useless. And for either, if you set A and B to zero and expect them to stay that way, well, then all the rates k must be zero too because otherwise A will not stay zero.

Comment: @BryanKrause: I'm using capital letters as the species and small letters as their concentration. `then all the rates k must be zero`: exactly! So, to me, I think if one sets the concentrations $a$ and $b$ to zero, then NO REACTION WILL OCCUR ANYMORE AND ALL SPECIES REMAIN STATIC. Don't you think?

Comment: Are you setting them to zero as an initial condition or decreeing that they stay zero forever? I would say yes, if a or b are products/reactants of a reaction and you order them to stay zero for ever, no reaction will occur. That is silly, and trivial - why even use the equations? If a=0 and b=0 to start, equation 2 won't happen because it is a one way reaction, B + X => C; if you have no B then you are missing a reactant, so nothing can happen. In equation 1, however, some 2X will become A and X, so even if a(0)==0, a(t)>0 where t is some time in the future.

Comment: (also none of this has anything to do with biology, you would say the same thing in chemistry, and in any other system described by such equations)

Comment: Also, shouldn't the second row of your matrix be [1 -1 -1]? Otherwise you are describing A <-> 2X rather than A + X <-> 2X

Comment: Wouldn't this be a better fit on [Math](https://math.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: @AliceD: I don't think so. Because my problem is fully context-dependent!

Comment: @BryanKrause: Thanks, mate. You're seemingly right about those entries.

Comment: I disagree that the problem here is context-dependent for biology, you are really just asking about implications of certain constraints on matrix algebra (i.e., if you say a=0 and da/dt=0), unless there is some other misunderstanding between us. But I don't think the question should be migrated to math, it needs some work and self-thought before it would be appropriate there.

Comment: Given the comments it seems the math behind it may need to be sorted out first before the biological interpretation can begin.

Comment: Stoichiometry matrix denotes by what numner different molecules change if a given reaction happens. It is static and does not change with time. What changes is the reaction rate. Your net accumulation rate (for all species dx/dt) would be S*r. Please try to read about this topic more carefully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stoichiometry matrix denotes by what number different molecules change if a given reaction happens. It is static and does not change with time. What changes is the reaction rate. Your net accumulation rate (for all species) would be

$$\frac{dx}{dt} = S\times r$$

Stoichiometry matrix cannot have all zero entries. It is meaningless (or it means that the reactions do not affect the molecules at all; which is meaningless)